# Removing Black edges from the UITableViewGroupedStyle in IOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

Hi can any one tell me how can i remove the black edges at the corner of mY UITableView GroupStyle.  i have create a custom view for my UITableView Cell. i have tried this code but it work in IOS 5 and not work in IOS 4.0 what the problem is that i have tried all the proposed solution Please Help!  
 `self.tableView = [UIColor ClearColor];` in viewDidLoad work in Ios 5 not in IOS 4 what problem is that .  
 when i run this on simulator 5.1 then it not show black edges but show black edges in simultor 4.3. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

To remove the borders from the cells:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: i dont want to remove the border i just want to remove the black edges on the corner. but any way this does not work for me. the problem is that in ios 5 there is no such a black corner but in ios 4 it display these corner

Comment: Not sure but try:
`tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

And if you putting table through xib :

Make **SeparatorStyle = Single Line**

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for helping me.

Actually this work for me

```
self.tableView backgroundcolor = [UIColor ClearColor];
```

but i was missing the `IBOutlet` of tableView so i connect the property of tableview with interface Builder it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the tableView's backgroundView with a new view.

I then relied on the tableView's backgroundColor property to set the color I wanted:

self.tableView.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];